# why am I seeing lots of stomp1.<mydomain> DNS queries from Google ip addresses?

Tags: domain-name-system

We maintain DNS service for > 100 domains, including some of our own ones and while wandering through the dns server logs I noticed a slow but more or less constant (~ 40 requests / hour) stream of dns requests for `stomp1.<our_own_domain>.<tld>` A record.

They are coming from *many different* ip addresses (with an average of one unique ip address every 2.5 dns requests, so we are literally seeing dns requests from hundreds of unique ip addresses) in the 74.125.0.0/16 netblock, which is assigned to Google.

Some empiric searching suggests that it could be used from "miscellaneous services" including Google App Engine, but it shouldn't be part of Google crawling activities.

We didn't have any dns record at that address, so just for the fun of it we added the record and pointed it to `127.0.0.1` with a ttl of many days: so far it did not have any effect on the stream of requests which is still going at ~ 40 reqs / hour.

As far as I can tell, some / many legitimate [STOMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_Text_Oriented_Messaging_Protocol) clients defaults to trying to resolve the `stomp1` hostname, but we never used anything like that. We also never run anything on Google's systems (eg. App Engine) and we never used any of their services in relation to our domain (eg. never used G Suite or anything). It also sounds strange to me that we are only seeing those kind of requests for a single domain out of >100.

Is there any "known and standard thing" that I'm totally missing here (like queries for spf records in dns, robots.txt in http servers, and so on...) or should I suspect some kind of misbehavior, targeted to our domain for some reason?

Comment: If the server/workstation running the STOMP client is configured to use Google's public resolvers 8.8.8.8 and/or 8.8.4.4 and has `<our_own_domain>.<tld>` as the search domain that might explain both how requests for a default `stomp1` get converted to `stomp1.<our_own_domain>.<tld>` as well as how the DNS queries would appear in your logs as originating from Google IP-addresses.

Comment: @HBruijn you should post your comment as an answer to allow me to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server/workstation running the STOMP client is configured to use Google's public resolvers 8.8.8.8 and/or 8.8.4.4 and it also has `<our_own_domain>.<tld>` as the search domain that is a plausible explanation for both how requests for a default `stomp1` get converted to `stomp1.<our_own_domain>.<tld>` as well as how the DNS queries would appear in your logs as originating from Google IP-addresses.

Comment: It never crossed my mind that dns queries from google ip's could be triggered by something on _our_ side that was using google dns - stupid me. But you were absolutely correct: we traced it down to some test systems that had Google DNS in their resolv.conf and Mcollective running, the latter uses STOMP and was querying for `stomp1`.